# Basic Constrained functional form

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $I \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ be an even functional.  There is a claim that then the restriction to the sphere has the following form for the Frechet derivative 
$$I|_{S^{n-1}}'(u) = I'(u)-(I'(u),u)u$$
I don't see why this is true.  Could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

The Fréchet derivative does not make sense here, because $I|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ is not a function defined on an open set of a linear space. I think what is meant here is the gradient of $I|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ as a function on the Riemannian manifold $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. That is a vector field, i. e. a section of the tangent bundle of the sphere, so embedded in the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^n$, at each point $u \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ it has to be orthogonal to $u$. In fact, it is the orthogonal projection of the gradient of $I$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ along $u$, and that is what the formula is supposed to mean.

Comment: Do you mean, the gradient of I (that is, not the gradient of $I|_{S^{n-1}}$) as a function on $S^{n-1}$, since you just said that the derivative does not make sense here?

Comment: also if this expression is orthogonal to $u$, then that means that we should (evaluating at $u$) that $(I'(u),u) - (I'(u),u)u = 0$.  This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE *Frechet derivative* (a concept of functional analysis) does not make sense for $I_{|S^{n-1}}$, but the *gradient* (concept of Riemannian geometry) does.

Comment: @Thomas I would be surprised, since the author makes no reference to Riemannian geometry.  This is in fact from a PDE book.  The goal is to prove that under the conditions for $I$ above, then $I|_{S^{n-1}}$ has at least $n$ distinct pairs of critical points, apparently first proved by Ljusternik and Schnirelmann.  This link is not the book I am studying, but it is by the same author with the same claim http://tinyurl.com/aq27j92  p.153-154

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE It is orthogonal to $u$: $(I'(u)-(I'(u),u)u,u) = 0$, since $(u,u) = 1$. I guess the author implicitely parametrizes the sphere as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, concatenates the parametrization with $I$. Then he can take the gradient, but has to push it forward to $\mathbb{R}^3$ via the derivative of the parametrization.